# Rolling Back a transaction from beforeCompletion TransactionSynchronization?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I am using Spring `TransactionSynchronizationManager` to register a `beforeCompletion` callback like below:

```
@Transactional
public void doTransaction() {
    //do DB stuff
    updateDB();

    //register a synchronization
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization() {
        @Override
        public void beforeCompletion() {
            if(!isCallApiSuccessful()) {
                //rollback the transaction
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Question is how do I roll-back transaction from the `beforeCompletion` callback ? Would throwing an exception work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would throwing an exception work?

No, it will not work because `beforeCompletion()` is for cleaning up resources.
Here is what throwing an exception has as effect according to the documentation :

> Throws:
>
> `java.lang.RuntimeException` - in case of errors; **will be logged but not
>   propagated** (note: do not throw TransactionException subclasses here!)

You should probably implement `void beforeCommit(boolean readOnly)` to achieve that and throws an `RuntimeException` inside it if you want to prevent the commit.
Here is what throwing an exception has as effect according to the documentation :

> Throws:
>
> `java.lang.RuntimeException` - in case of errors; **will be propagated to
>   the caller** (note: do not throw TransactionException subclasses here!)